# Why users disable the WordPress update?

Tags: plugins, themes, security, upgrade, updates

Users install plugins which disable update reminders.

Plugins:

- [disable WordPress Core Updates](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-wordpress-core-update/)
- [disable WordPress Plugin Updates](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-wordpress-core-update/)
- [disable WordPress Theme Updates](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-wordpress-theme-updates/)

Look at the counter of plugins downloads.

I know that some users change the WordPress core files or plugin or theme files, but there is WordPress hooks and child themes.

If user will disable the updates:

- user will not see new features of newer WP versions or plugins or themes;
- user will use software without bug fixes and probably with security issues

**So why users disable the WordPress update?** Is there any other reasons disabling updates except of modifying the files?

Comment: obviously because they don't know what they are going to lose. :)

Answer (score 4):

I know that when i disable the WordPress updates its mainly to allow me to first test the updates and then go and update in my clients sites instead of them just clicking links around and usually messing things up.

Answer (score 3):

1. There is no point disabling updates. Its a security risks.
2. If a theme doesn't provide enough flexibility to customize through its theme option one should use a child theme. That way he can update the original theme and and take advantage of new features.
3. If you using a older version wordpress you are wide open to attack. Trust me they will get in sooner or later.
4. Stay away from developer who modify core files. I remember once i had to change/improve a core function. Instead i change it on core i copy the whole function and name it something new and add it on my themes `functions.php`.
5. **Some developers** (who are maintaining a site) sometime does disables the update. Because they don't want owners (who have admin capability) to mess the site up. I think that might be a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Users disable update because in some configurations the requests needed to check if the update is necesary time-out adding 3seconds of waiting for the first byte back from wordpress (ie update adds 3 seconds of waiting to some requests)